# How do I see response text in debugger?

Tags: alamofire

If this is my request, how do I see the response's text in the debugger window, in particular when there's an error?

```
let request = Alamofire.request(
                    webServiceUrl + url, method: method, parameters: parameters)
                    .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                    .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])

request.responseJSON { response in ... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my response handler, I added...

```
if let resp = response.data {

   NSLog("Server Response: \(NSString(data: resp, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))")
}
```